# Get language wise numbers using culture info in c#

Tags: c#, .net, numbers, native, cultureinfo

I'm working on language wise numbers and I'm doing it via CultureInfo.

CultureInfo class provide Native digit for Arabic and Gujarati language but not for Hindi.

For example: 
My number is in English: 123456
Same number in Gujarati language: ૧૨૩૪૫6 (This is working fine)
For English language: १२३४५६ *This is not working*

What is the alternate option to display Hindi Native digit?

Example : 
I want to display numbers in Hindi language: ०,१,२,३,४,५,६,७,८,९.

Here Is my code snippet:

```
CultureInfo languageculture = new CultureInfo("hi-IN");
NumberFormatInfo languageNumberFormat = languageculture.NumberFormat;
string[] nativeDigits = languageNumberFormat.NativeDigits;
string str5 = ConvertToMyLanguageDigits(i.ToString(), mydiditesgu);
```

Conversion (replace number) method:

```
private static string ConvertToMyLanguageDigits(string number, string[] myNative)
{
    string myNewMuber = string.Empty;
    myNewMuber = number;
    Regex rgx = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]");
    string number1 = rgx.Replace(number, "");
    var aa = number1.ToCharArray().Distinct().ToArray();
    foreach (var item in aa)
    {
        if (!myNative.Any(x => x.Contains(item)))
        {
            myNewMuber = myNewMuber.Replace(item.ToString(), myNative[int.Parse(item.ToString())].ToString());
        }
    }
    return myNewMuber;
}
```

Comment: its just unicode right, Hindi is still base 10?

Comment: Does `"hi"` or `"hi-IN"` not work? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc233982.aspx

Comment: did u install hindi language pack for nopCommerce?

Comment: Hi Jordrell,
Here is code which Bilal is using
`CultureInfo languageculture = new CultureInfo("hi-IN");
NumberFormatInfo languageNumberFormat = languageculture.NumberFormat;
string[] nativeDigits = languageNumberFormat.NativeDigits;
string str5 = ConvertToMyLanguageDigits(i.ToString(), mydiditesgu);`

Comment: @BILAL SURAWALA, did u install hindi language pack?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the language pack installed on Windows, can't you do.

```
var hindiCulture = new CultureInfo("hi-IN");
```

To get the right culture. Then

```
var hindiDigits = hindiCulture.NumberFormat.NativeDigits;
```

to get the right digits?

---

For example, [as demonstrated here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/d5oSSa)

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var hindiCulture = new CultureInfo("hi-IN");
        Console.WriteLine(hindiCulture.EnglishName);
        Console.WriteLine(hindiCulture.NativeName);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", hindiCulture.NumberFormat.NativeDigits));
    }
}
```

outputs

```
Hindi (India)
हिंदी (भारत)
०१२३४५६७८९
```

---

[As demonstrated here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Wx8BAt), If I do

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var hindiCulture = new CultureInfo("hi-IN");
        Console.WriteLine(hindiCulture.EnglishName);
        Console.WriteLine(hindiCulture.NativeName);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", hindiCulture.NumberFormat.NativeDigits));
        Console.WriteLine(
            ConvertToMyLanguageDigits("0123456789", 
            hindiCulture.NumberFormat.NativeDigits));
    }

    private static string ConvertToMyLanguageDigits(string number, string[] myNative)
        {
            string myNewMuber = string.Empty;
            myNewMuber = number;
            Regex rgx = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]");
            string number1 = rgx.Replace(number, "");
            var aa = number1.ToCharArray().Distinct().ToArray();
            foreach (var item in aa)
            {
                if (!myNative.Any(x => x.Contains(item)))
                {
                    myNewMuber = myNewMuber.Replace(
                        item.ToString(), 
                        myNative[int.Parse(item.ToString())].ToString());
                }
            }
            return myNewMuber;
       }
}
```

The output is

```
Hindi (India)
हिंदी (भारत)
०१२३४५६७८९
०१२३४५६७८९
```

There is no problem with your code or with .Net, I suspect you don't have you system set up properly, do you have the language pack installed?

Comment: No, it's returing english digits for Hindi language.

Comment: @RajuPaladiya, see the demo on fiddle linked here. It does worked for Hindi.

Comment: but this is not working with nopCommerce application.
I tried with console application with asp.net core and it seems working fine, but with nopCommerce-4.00 it not working

Comment: @RajuPaladiya, So its not a code problem, its a configuration problem. Unless nopCommerce has some extra problematic code you have not posted.

Comment: in console application, CultureInfo refer to mscorlib.dll (http://prntscr.com/kg7o5x) while in nopCommerce 4.00 code it refer to System.Runtime

Comment: @RajuPaladiya When targeting the .Net Framework System.Runtime is in mscorlib.dll

Comment: It seems nopCommerce missing something in structure, I'm going to report bug in nopCommerce